# Setting IsolatedStorage quota for .NET 4 desktop applications

Tags: .net-4.0, isolatedstorage

[This page about storage quotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbe2d5h0.aspx) says to use the mscorcfg tool.   BUT [the mscorcfg page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx) says the tool is only for older versions of .NET

So... what's the .NET 4 way of setting this value for desktop (not Silverlight) applications?

Comment: The documentation claims it is stored as evidence with the assembly. I was able to us `storeadm.exe` to enumerate the stores on my machine, but I don't know how to adjust the evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at how this is done, it appears you will need to edit the Application Manifest using a tool like [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx). If you open up your application's manifest and look under the *Permissions Required* entry you will see that most likely it has the *Permission set type* of **FullTrust**, i.e. no quota.

If you change the Permission set type to LocalIntranet or to Internet, you will see an entry in the Details area like so:

```
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             version="1"
             Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser"
             UserQuota="9223372036854775807"
             Expiry="9223372036854775807"
             Permanent="True"/>
```

Or

```
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             version="1"
             Allowed="ApplicationIsolationByUser"
             UserQuota="1024000"/>
```

You will likely need to edit the Permission set to include the `IsolatedStorageFilePermission` evidence, run your application, and have it Get/Create the User store. You can verify it worked with the proper quota using the [`storeadm.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezabwsbk.aspx) tool.

Answer (score 0):

[IsolatedStorage.IncreaseQuotaTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.increasequotato.aspx) should be what you want...

Comment: "Currently, none of the hosts in the .NET Framework provide this customization, so IncreaseQuotaTo always returns false." [IsolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato.aspx)

Comment: You are looking at the IsolatedStorageFile class, I pointed to the IsolatedStorage class. Have you tried with the IsolatedStorage class?

Comment: I did sir, however, `IsolatedStorage` is an *abstract* base class. It has one concrete implementation `IsolatedStorageFile`, which does not implement `IncreaseQuotaTo` under the desktop hosts.